# Is it needed to install MongoDB locally to connect a PHP project with a remote MongoDB server?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am trying to run a PHP project which is connected to a remote MongoDB server on my local machine.

I already made sure that the PHP-mongo.dll extension is installed.

Now, is it necessary for me to install MongoDB locally as well?

Comment: If you don't want to host the database locally, then no. Are you experiencing a specific problem right now?

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the response.  Yes i am facing an issues.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the response.  Yes, I am facing an issue. I installed PHP7.3.6 - Xampp V3.2.4 and then downloaded php_mongo-1.7.4-7.3-ts-vc15-x64 thread-safe and moved the php_mongodb.dll to PHP folder and added the extensions as well. Still, the issue of mongo driver exists

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what your error is. Show the code which causes it. And add that info about the configuration to your question as well please

Comment: @ADyson, you should check the extension is correctly installed by using either `php -i` or `phpinfo()` and update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a local MongoDB server. It is possible to do all of the development using Atlas.

Comment: can you share a link where it show to connect with remote mongodb server and perform crud operations